# Error: SIGSEGV when running application on Mono

Tags: c#, mono, debian, segmentation-fault, raspberry-pi

After hours of trying to get this to work, I have decided it's time to post.

I have a C# Windows Forms application that is quite basic, and I can complie and run it fine on windows. The whole project is designed to work on a Pi though, so I moved the project over to it and compiled. After a couple of hours of finally getting it to compile (foundout I had to reference the MySql.Data.dll file) it compiled with no errors!

But then I run

```
Mono Administration.exe
```

and I got this huge error, that I can find very little about online:

```
pi@raspberrypi /media/WAYNEIO/pi/ProjectNibiru/ProjectNibiru $ mono Administration.exe
Stacktrace:

  at System.Drawing.Font.CreateFont (string,single,System.Drawing.FontStyle,System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit,byte,bool) <0x00143>
  at System.Drawing.Font..ctor (string,single,System.Drawing.FontStyle,System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit,byte,bool) <0x0007f>
  at System.Drawing.Font..ctor (string,single,string) <0x00057>
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Drawing.Font..ctor (string,single,string) <0xffffffff>
  at System.Drawing.SystemFonts.get_DefaultFont () <0x00073>
  at System.Windows.Forms.Theme..ctor () <0x0002f>
  at System.Windows.Forms.ThemeWin32Classic..ctor () <0x00013>
  at System.Windows.Forms.ThemeVisualStyles..ctor () <0x00013>
  at System.Windows.Forms.ThemeEngine..cctor () <0x0007f>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_void (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
  at System.Windows.Forms.X11DesktopColors..cctor () <0x000bb>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_void (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11..ctor () <0x001af>
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.GetInstance () <0x00073>
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI..cctor () <0x00157>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_void (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles () <0x00023>
  at ProjectNibiru.Program.Main () <0x0000b>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_void (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>

Native stacktrace:


Debug info from gdb:

Cannot access memory at address 0x0
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x4093b460 (LWP 2224)]
0x40085f30 in read () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
  Id   Target Id         Frame
  2    Thread 0x4093b460 (LWP 2224) "mono" 0x40084d84 in sem_wait@@GLIBC_2.4 () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
* 1    Thread 0x400cd000 (LWP 2223) "mono" 0x40085f30 in read () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0

Thread 2 (Thread 0x4093b460 (LWP 2224)):
#0  0x40084d84 in sem_wait@@GLIBC_2.4 () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00195a40 in mono_sem_wait ()
#2  0x000ea384 in ?? ()
#3  0x000ea384 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 1 (Thread 0x400cd000 (LWP 2223)):
#0  0x40085f30 in read () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x40085770 in __pthread_enable_asynccancel () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x00000000 in ?? ()

=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
used by your application.
=================================================================

Aborted
```

Can anyone offer advice as to why this might be appearing, and how to resolve the issue please?

Things to note; This occurs no matter if i compile with "Xbuild" or with "dmcs" or if its compiled in windows, and copied across. Also compiling a basic hello world script works fine, so it's probably to do with Windows.Forms or MySql.Data. Also the PI is running Debian.

Comment: The better question may be, how do I debug a SIGSEGV in linux

Comment: You can use `mono --trace` to get a better idea of what's happening. For most detail, you need a `gdb` with mono support and mono libraries with debug info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is to update to the lastest version of mono, and make sure it's being run on soft-float debian.

Answer found by following this thread http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=11634

Comment: The Raspberry Pi images used to be armel (soft-float) a couple years ago, but these days it seems like all the readily available Raspberry Pi images are armhf (hardware float).  Do you know a good soft-float image for the Raspberry Pi that is still being maintained, or have you heard of any other solutions for this SIGSEGV?

Answer (score 2):

After reading your question more carefully I can see that it is specific segfault saying `Cannot access memory at address 0x0`, so it probably accessed pointer returned because of error. For example program asked for something like *give me handle to font X* and function returned null pointer for some reason. Some possible solutions you can try:

- compile mono from sources, make a breakpoint near the failing function and step while observing variable values, maybe they'll tell you something;
- install `mono-complete` package if you did not already;
- try to install font used by this application (although one can tell from the stack trace that the app is looking for the default font ;))

You may also look at the sources. The interesting parts are probably:

- https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Drawing/System.Drawing/Font.cs#L58
- https://github.com/mono/libgdiplus/blob/master/src/font.c#L800

**Old answer:**

There aren't much details here, but whenever I encounter the segfault with Windows Forms application, my first guess is that some UI controls are accessed from the different that UI thread. Many times the same application will not crash on MS implemenation of Windows Forms, nonetheless this approach is incorrect. Maybe that's your problem?

List of the other possible reasons for the error includes the Mono bug (give us the version number) or some kind of bug in the third party native library, if used. With the latter case it is indeed worthwhile to use GDB (previously compiling those libraries with some debug options, like g3). To not being disturbed by the signals sent by the garbage collector remember to issue

```
handle SIGXCPU SIG33 SIG35 SIGPWR nostop noprint
```

during the GDB session.

Comment: Thanks, great reply.How do i ensure that all the UI controls are running off the same thread? As for third party native libraries, i also tried this with a basic windows forms application and still got the error. The mono version is Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-5). The error mentions system fonts

Comment: @Wayneio as for "how to run all UI controls from the same thread": If you want to manipulate UI from another thread use Control.Invoke() with the suitable delegate function. This hands the delegate to the thread owning the control you're trying to influence and runs it on there: Exactly what you're looking for. A bit like they made that for situations like these :D